# SQL Server pivot a table without aggregating

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to pivot a table without aggregating or roll up the nulls?

For example I have a query something like

```
select 
    PERS_AREA_NAME,
    EMP_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + EMP_LAST_NAME as 'CHIEF COUNSEL',
    NULL AS 'APPROVER'
from 
    dbo.IES_HR_EMPLOYEES
where 
    JOB_NAME like '%Chf Cnsl%'  

UNION ALL  

select 
    PERS_AREA_NAME,
    NULL,
    EMP_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + EMP_LAST_NAME
from 
    dbo.IES_HR_EMPLOYEES
where
    JOB_NAME like '%Dep Sec%'
order by 
    1
```

That results in

```
PERS_AREA_NAME CHIEF_COUNSEL APPROVER
-----------------------------------------
one            Bob Jones     Null
one            Fred Smith    Null
one            Null          Mary Smith
two            John Doe      Null
two            Null          Will Jones
two            Null          Fred Stevens
```

Is it possible to rollup the nulls?

```
    PERS_AREA_NAME  CHIEF_COUNSEL APPROVER
    ------------------------------------------------
    one             Bob Jones     Mary Smith
    one             Fred Smith    Null
    two             John Doe      Will Jones
    two             Null          Fred Stevens
```

Comment: Why should Mary Smith be associated with Bob Jones and not Fred Smith?   By the way, this really isn't a PIVOT at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a UNION ALL of the two queries, do a FULL OUTER JOIN using ROW_NUMBER() as the JOIN condition.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think the best way is to forget multiple subqueries and just use a form of aggregation:

```
select pers_area_name,
       max(chief_counsel) as chief_counsel,
       max(approver) as approver
from (select PERS_AREA_NAME, (EMP_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + EMP_LAST_NAME) as name,
             (CASE WHEN JOB_NAME like '%Chf Cnsl%' THEN name END) as chief_counsel,
             (CASE WHEN JOB_NAME like '%Dep Sec%' THEN name END) as approver,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN JOB_NAME like '%Chf Cnsl%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      from dbo.IES_HR_EMPLOYEES e cross apply
           (values (EMP_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + EMP_LAST_NAME)) v(name)
      where JOB_NAME like '%Chf Cnsl%' OR JOB_NAME like '%Dep Sec%'
    ) e
group by PERS_AREA_NAME, seqnum;
order by 1;
```

The idea behind this is simpler than the query.  Basically, it is just keeping track of the chief counsels and approvers in a single subquery.  The key idea is the `row_number()` by job function.  This allows the aggregation to pick up values for each in each row in the result set.

This does assume that a single person (well, row in the employees table) does not have a job title that contains both "Chf Cnsl" and "Dep Sec".